# New app version uploaded in App Distribution don't show up in Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I uploaded a new version of my application in AppStore but it doesn't appear in Crashlytic version list.
But in Analytics I can see my new version.
I uploaded this version 2 weeks ago.

Comment: have you tried crashing your app for the new version earlier? If so, was it logging the crashes properly in Crashlytics for both previous and current app versions?

Comment: @Saurabh How can I generate crash? So why analytics show my new version? firebase activation is working.

Comment: Make sure you have configured the FirebaseCrashlytics right - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#swift. To generate a crash for testing purpose - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios

Comment: @Saurabh I am using Carthage. https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/carthage/
My analytics is working but Crashlytic has the problem yet.